# Capture UIKeyCommand for Function Keys on iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am trying to capture the F5 key on an external bluetooth keyboard in an iOS application. I have set up the UIKeyCommands, yet I cannot figure out how to create a UIKeyCommand that would capture the function keys. There is no option for UIKeyModifierFunction.

Comment: What happens if you use the `"F5"` string for the initialiser?

Answer (score 0):

You should trying using `var NSF5FunctionKey: Int`. Take a look at this link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535851-function_key_unicodes

Comment: But for creating a UIKeyCommand object, we need to specify a string input. But NSF5FunctionKey is an int. A working code snippet would be greatly helpful.